# How to design good looking GWT applications?

Tags: java, user-interface, gwt

I'm creating a Web app using plain GWT (no wrappers such as GXT). The problem is that a good look & feel for a GWT app is very hard to achieve using only UiBinder. My workflow for now is:

1. Create HTML and CSS with Dreamweaver/Photoshop
2. Put the HTML resources on the server and fetch them using GWT's Client Bundle.
3. "Inject" widgets into HTMLPanels who where initialized with the resource HTML files from the server.

As you can see it's more of a "template" way of doing things. My UiBinders are almost empty files though.

I'm concerned about XSS holes by working as I do. So I was thinking of eventually putting each HTML file into it's UIBinder xml file. Does it have to be so complicated (long)??? Can anyone tell me how they managed to get good looking GWT apps using only UiBinder?

I'm not interested in responses including any GXT, SmartGWT solutions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Our process, which works great (activegrade.com):

1. Photoshop -> Html + Css + Images
2. Html -> UiBinder; Css + Images -> ClientBundle

Your third step sounds like it's re-inventing what UiBinder already does for you.

The only thing we do outside this process is figure out what kind of html is produced by the widgets we're going to use.  For instance, MenuBars make `<table>`s, so we say, "Hey, make the prototype out of tables." `FlowPanel`s make `<div>`s, so we say, "Hey, please make the prototype out of divs."  We got burned once and had to re-do the html.

Addendum example:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <ui:with field="resources"
        type="com.activegrade.client.teacher.dialogfillers.standarddetails.StandardDetail.StandardDetailResources" />
    <ui:with field="dialogresources"
        type="com.activegrade.client.resources.DialogResources" />
    <ui:style>

    </ui:style>
    <g:HTMLPanel
        styleName="{resources.css.aNameIChose} {dialogresources.css.agwForm}">
        <div class="{dialogresources.css.agwFormBlock}">
            <label>Name</label>
            <g:TextBox ui:field="nameText" />
        </div>
        <div class="{dialogresources.css.agwFormBlock}">
            <label>Description</label>
            <g:TextArea ui:field="descriptionText" />
        </div>
        <div class="{dialogresources.css.agwFormBlockLeft}">
            <label>Grading Scale</label>
            <g:ListBox ui:field="scaleSelector" />
        </div>
        <div class="{dialogresources.css.agwFormBlockRight}">
            <label>Calculation Method</label>
            <g:ListBox ui:field="calculationMethodSelector" />
        </div>
        <div class="{dialogresources.css.agwFormBlock}">
            <label>Tags</label>
            <div class="{resources.css.tagdiv}">
                <g:FlowPanel ui:field="panelForTags" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <g:Button ui:field="addTagsButton">Add Tags</g:Button>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Creates:

[image]

Comment: I like your answer and your site! This is where I was confused. So you check your output and of GWT widgets and create html to "paste it in UiBinder files"? But do you use GWT widgets such as FlowPanel in the end result?

Comment: Absolutely. We replace bits of HTML with the appropriate GWT widgets.  Above, we wrapped our html in an HtmlPanel instead of a div, used g:ListBox widgets instead of selects, etc.  The header, OK & Cancel buttons are defined in a more general dialog widget we made, but the process is the same.

Comment: PPS: Our designer, who doesn't know Java, created this UiBinder file.

Answer (score 5):

Why jump through so many hoops? Write the GWT interface, look at the markup it produces, then write CSS to make it look the way you want. You can either integrate the finished CSS into the binder templates or just link it as an external file.

Comment: How do you look at the "markup it produces"? Firebug? I'm not a designer so for me using Dreamweaver is such a performance improvement but I than waste time going through my hoops.

Comment: "I'm not a designer." Nor am I! I can muddle through, but if I really wanted something to look good, I would hire a professional.

Comment: When I say look good, I mean better than 3 colors as if I had created it in notepad. This is an open source project, so as long as no one knows how to do this, well I can only hope for the best.